# Selecting a string and ignoring spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

Does anyone know how to select the text "*Some words & things (lp4)*" below?

I am trying to select [*something*] that is between two spaces `\s` and that has one or more `+` words `\b` in the selection

```js
var string = '     \n       Some words & things (lp4)    ';
var regexp = /\s[\b*]\s/i;
var selection = string.match(regexp);

console.log(selection);
```

Comment: Not clear, what are matching rules?

Comment: Why not `string.trim()`? Sorry, but `/\s[\b*]\s/i` does not look like a meaningful attempt.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Because there might be different amount of spaces each iteration. There will be at least one space in the end though. I am sorry I couldn't provide anything meaningfull since I am bad at regex.

Comment: Please add explanation of what you are doing to the question.

Comment: `string.trim()` appears to do what you want. It removes all leading and trailing whitespace characters.

Comment: Ok, I am trying to select [*something*] that is between two spaces `\s` and that has one or more `+` words in the selection.

Comment: Something like `s.match(/\s(\S+(?:\s+\S+)+)\s/)[1]`?

Comment: Thank you all for your answers everyone! I really appreciate your comments!

Comment: Please, clarify your question by editing it

Answer (score 2):

It is not exactly clear to me what you are trying to achieve. So I will cover two possibilities.

### 1st case: remove whitespaces

If all you basically want is to remove leading and trailing whitespace characters, then `trim()` will be enough to do that:

```
var string = '     \n       Some words & things (lp4)    ';
var selection = string.trim();
console.log(selection);
```

This will log

```
Some words & things (lp4)
```

to the console.

### 2nd case: replace only the words

In this case a regular expression can be helpful indeed.

```
var string = '     \n       Some words & things (lp4)    ';
var regexp = /\s+(\S+(\s\S+)*)\s+/i;
var match = string.match(regexp);

if (match === null) {
  console.log('No match was found!');
} else {
  console.log('Match (words only) is: ' + match[1]);
  var replaced = string.replace(match[1], 'New replacement text');
  console.log('Replaced value: "' + replaced + '"');
}
```

The regular expression here is `\s+(\S+(\s\S+)*)\s+`. Let me break that down into pieces:

- `\s+`: look for whitespace characters (`\s`), and allow one or more occurences (`+`) - that is the whitespace at the beginning
- `\S+`: look for non-whitespace characters (`\S`), and allow zero or more occurences (`+`) - this is basically a single word
- `(\s\S+)*`: look for a single whitespace character (`\s`) followed by one or more occurences (`+`) of non-whitespace characters (`\S`), and allow the whole thing zero or more times - these are basically all words after the first word
- the outer paranthesis `()` are for capturing all the words in one group - this will be the first group in the match
- `\s+`: look for whitespace characters (`\s`), and allow one or more occurences (`+`) - that is the whitespace at the end

Finally, the output of this code would be:

```
Match (words only) is: Some words & things (lp4) 
Replaced value: "     
   New replacement text    "
```

That is, the whitespaces will be kept in the output, as can be seen by the position of the double quotes.

Comment: @Clone: Since this question (as of now) is not clear to me, I added a possible 2nd case for replacement of "only the words" with the help of regular expressions. Maybe that is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you try to remove multiples of whitespace:

```js
var string = '     \n       Some words   & things (lp4)    ';
var regexp = /\s{2,}/gm;
console.log(string.replace(regexp, ' ').trim());
```

Comment: What does `\s{2,}` this mean?According to documentation "n{X,}  matches any string that contains a sequence of at least X n's" does this mean that your expression selects a string that contains at least two spaces?

Comment: @Clone `{2,}` is a (greedy) [quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) that matches whitespace (`[\r\n\t\f\v ]`) characters two or as many times as possible. So, if you have unnecessary whitespace somewhere between - you can get rid of it too that way.